# ZSH - auto_cd with symlink not working

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh

I've the following dir structure:

`$HOME/tools/scala -> scala-2.10.3`

`$HOME/tools/scala-2.10.3`

In the `$HOME/.zshenv` file I defined the following env variable:

`SCALA_HOME=$HOME/tools/scala`

Then when I enter `$SCALA_HOME` in shell and confirm it (`auto_cd` option is set) I don't get moved to the directory `$SCALA_HOME` instead I receive the following error:

> zsh: no such file or directory: /User/opal/tools/scala
>
> zsh: exit 127   $SCALA_HOME

Can ZSH recognize the symlink correctly? I've no idea where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in .zshenv file. Everything works great and zsh handles symlinks in env variables correctly.